# Passing a value to PHP from jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get a value back to PHP which I can work with and send to the database. I don't seem to be able to do that using the GET type of jQuery AJAX. Here's the PHP I'm using to catch the value:

```
<?php require_once("header.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("class.php"); ?>
<?php

//$month = $_POST['month'];
//$year = $_POST['year'];

$month = 8;
$year = 2013;
$numDays = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
$empty = "<table class='box'><td>&nbsp</td></table>";

$cal = new calendar();
$cal->mkMonth($month);
$cal->emptyDays($empty, $numDays, $month, $year);
$cal->mkdays($numDays, $month, $year);

echo "</div>";


echo "<div id='jresult'>";
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
   echo ($_GET['id']);
}

echo "</div>";
?>
```

Here's the jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box").mouseenter(function(){$(this).css("background-color", "red");});
    $(".box").mouseout(function(){$(this).css("background-color", "transparent");});
    $(".box").click(function() {
        date_time = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(date_time);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/book.me/loop.php',
            data: "id=" + $(date_time).val(),
            success: function(data){
                alert('successful');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I'm trying to pass in the id of the `.box` class element to the `date_time` variable which works, but it doesn't seem to be working when I call `$_GET['id']` in PHP. I'm just getting an undefined value back.

Comment: # missing in selector of date_time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send the id attribute, not the value, you can use

```
$(".box").click(function() {
    date_time = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/book.me/loop.php',
        data: "id=" + date_time,
        success: function(data){
            alert('successful');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: hmm.. I seem to still be getting undefined index back from php, but I still get the "successful" message...

Comment: are you trying to send the id of the element that was clicked as the data?

Comment: @MylonJamesMarcell see update, also in PHP you should use `if(isset($_GET['id']))` instead of `if($_GET['id'])` to prevent undefined index errors

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be echoing back anything, but I'm getting the successful message. It seems like PHP isn't picking up the value with $_GET for whatever reason.

Comment: and you're certain your `.box` element has an id? can you post a sample of your markup and the complete php code?

Comment: I passed date_time to the alert, and it returned the id perfectly. Not sure why it won't then pass to PHP. It really doesn't seem like there should be any problem...

Comment: I'll post more code though, there must be something I'm missing.

Comment: @MylonJamesMarcell what does your HTML look like, where are the ids for your `.box` elements? also how are you testing if the php is echoing the value or not? and can you check the Network Tab on your browser's developer tools to analyze the data being sent?

Comment: Ok, I may have made some progress here. The method I'm using to test it is the line where I echo the value back on the page: `echo ($_GET['id']);`
When I go to network in development tools it states that I'm getting the appropriate id value back to the PHP page, but it was only after I used `data: "id=" + date_time,` in my jQuery.
The problem seems to be that the id just isn't echoing back, which is really weird. I've worked quite a bit with PHP and have never seen anything like this.

Comment: @MylonJamesMarcell but where are you expecting to see the result being echoed? and yes there was a closure issue with my answer, the thing is that you need to save a reference to the clicked element before the ajax call so you can use it in your data parameter, so using your variable `date_time` will work well

Comment: On the loop.php page. When I remove the `if(isset($_GET['id']) {}` I get undefined index where the `echo ($_GET['id']);` is, even when the id value is passed to the page.

Comment: but you do understand that with ajax the `loop.php` page is never shown in the browser right? with ajax the page is never refreshed, instead you get the server response as a string in your success callback, so the only way to test this is if you use `console.log(data)` in your success function, then you should see all the markup generated in `loop.php` on your browser's console

Comment: Ok, my apologies for the confusion. It makes perfect sense to me now. I know what I need to do. I have worked very little with Ajax and I still have quite a bit of learning to do. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Don't worry, we've all been at the beginner stage at some point, and that's actually the main thing you need to know about ajax, the fact that the response is not shown in your browser, but rather it's returned to your callback function. Anyway, glad you sorted things out, best of luck with your project!

Answer (score 2):

You can reference the clicked `.box` by using `$(this)`:

```
$(".box").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/book.me/loop.php',
        data: {
            id: $(this).val()
        },
        success: function(data){
            alert('successful');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you should set the data like this:

```
$(".box").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/book.me/loop.php',
        data: "id=" + this.id,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: { id: $(this).val() },
        success: function(data){
            alert('successful');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#' + date_time).val()
```